# How can I make ITD available in the code of the aspect subject?

Tags: aspectj

I am not sure if my terminology is right, but here is what I want. I have an aspect that injects a Log field into certain types, here is the aspect code:

```
public aspect LoggingAspect {
  private interface HttpHandlerType {}
  declare parents: (@Path *) implements HttpHandlerType;

  private Logger HttpHandlerType.Log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

  pointcut httpHandlerMethods(HttpHandlerType o) : within(HttpHandlerType+) && 
    execution(@(GET || PUT || POST || DELETE) public * *.*(..)) && this(o);

  before(HttpHandlerType o): httpHandlerMethods(o) {
    if (o.Log.isInfoEnabled()) {
      o.Log.info(logMethod(thisJoinPoint));
    }
  }

  after(HttpHandlerType o) returning (Object result): httpHandlerMethods(o) {
    if (o.Log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      o.Log.debug(logMethod(thisJoinPoint, result));
    }
  }

  after(HttpHandlerType o) throwing (Exception e): httpHandlerMethods(o) {
    if (o.Log.isEnabledFor(Level.ERROR)) {
      o.Log.error(logMethod(thisJoinPoint), e);
    }
  }

  private static String logMethod(JoinPoint jp) {
    ...
  }

  private static String logMethod(JoinPoint jp, Object result) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The question is how the aspect subjects can make use of this field. For instance, here is a sample class affected by this aspect:

```
@Path("user")
public class UserHandler {
  @GET
  @Path("{id}")
  public User getUser(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The question is how the code of getUser can utilize the Log field injected by the aspect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the visibility of the log field from private to public and this should work.

Comment: Thanks, in this example it is enough. However, there are problems in other cases - http://aspectj.2085585.n4.nabble.com/How-can-I-make-ITD-available-in-the-code-of-the-aspect-subject-td4169901.html